# Как сделать шар (не круг)?

Tags: html, css

подскажите как сделать шар по средством css, чтобы на нем можно было поставить цифру, например шар номер 3, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что это фото, но реально ли и как сделать похожее?

Comment: Взять фото, замазать цифру в фотошопе и просто поставить его как фон?

Comment: Здесь шар с бликом:
https://mojwp.ru/vozdushnye-shary-css.html

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 10):

Посмотрите [эту статью](https://cssanimation.rocks/spheres/), очень подробно все разбирается.
По сути ***шар/сфера*** это тот же круг на `css`, но с добавлением заливки в виде градиента.

```css
.circle {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100px 100px, #5cabff, #000);
}
```

```html
<figure class="circle"></figure>
```

После просто добавляете нужную цифру псевдо-элементом, либо дополнительным элементом и позиционируете ее.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/JebBzo)

Comment: и от меня плюс за находку отличной статьи

Comment: И в прям  статья классная...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, как по мне слишком затасканная тема, решение можно найти сразу же, как только написать в поиске "Как сделать окружность на `CSS`"=) Да и тут слишком часто подобные вопросы задавались, которые вскоре дубликатами были отмечены

Comment: @Arthur Чем больше ты будешь узнавать, тем больше тебе будет казаться, что всё знакомо и просто. Вся соль, как обычно бывает в нюансах.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, не совсем, но правда в твоих словах есть=)